# Is $\ell_\infty$ a $\max$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum, maxima-minima

Let $x(n)$ a sequence in real numbers. Consider $A=\sup \left\{ |x(n)| :  n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} $ .
Is $A$ a $\max$ at the same time? i.e. Is the equality $A=\max \left\{ |x(n)| :  n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$ correct ?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.**

Consider for instance $(x_n)_n$ with
$$
x_n = 1-\frac{1}{n+1}\,.
$$
The supremum of the sequence is $1$. Yet, the sequence has no maximum.